# How to reconfigure RSS Feed causing server problems

Tags: php, sql-server, rss, webserver

I have been dealing with a problem where my RSS feed (Simple for loop, sets it into valid rss formatting) has been fetched by sites to send the posts to Twitter/facebook and when it is fetched, it is crashing my entire server.

It's confusing because, the RSS feed loads perfect on validators, rss readers, in firefox's built in url reader and I can't seem to figure out why only when the feeds are fetched, will it crash  my server.

Is this a known problem where sites that fetch the data run into a problem with taking too much memory?

I run free -m right before it is fetched, have 250+ MB of free space, right after, its down to 5MB and a site that won't load.  What can you do to fix this type of problem? Is this a load balancing issue? An issue with my RSS feed? Should I use feedburner? Will that solve the problem?

UPDATE: I tried feedburner, same problem.